# PUT http://localhost:8000/controller/1 500 (Internal Server Error) when edit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I tried using ajax and datatable for my homework with laravel ofc. When I tried to edit some data in my crud, I get this error:

> *PUT http://localhost:8000/categories/1 500 (Internal Server Error)*

Any advice?

My controller :

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $categories = Category::findOrFail($id); 
        return view('categories.form', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'category_name' => 'required|string|' . $id
        ]);

        $categories = Category::findOrFail($id);

        $categories->update($request->all());
    }
```

My App.js :

```
$('#modal-btn-save').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#modal-body form'),
        url = form.attr('action'),
        method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

    form.find('.help-block').remove();
    form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            form.trigger('reset');
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
            $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();

            Swal.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Sukses !',
                text: 'Data berhasil di simpan !'
            });
        },
```

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it barely tells us anything. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. Please do that and then [edit] your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Like Chris says you can check the laravel log file, or if you prefer in browser: open the console/dev tools, select network tab and press any red item and preview it to see the error in detail.

Comment: Well, when I read the console, in the network tab, it said error' in my app.js on line 32, which is means, the line $.ajax, in my syntax that I already post, sorry for incomplete information, im new here

Comment: you haven't add csrf_token() in your form...may this occuring this problem

Comment: in the meta on app.blade ? i've already write it